# Using a list as arguments in a function

Tags: assignment

This might sound a little silly question but I cannot get my code work. Here is the problem:

I have quite a few lists of data which are basically beam profiles. I am using `Manipulate` to find a fit for each one of them. Then I extract the fit parameter from `Manipulate` using `Dynamic` which gives me a list of numbers. Finally, this is the part where I have problem, I want to use these number in the fitting function and use it somewhere else.

Here is the code:

```
data={
0.176471, 0.168627, 0.184314, 0.168627, 0.164706, 0.168627, 0.172549, \
0.160784, 0.172549, 0.164706, 0.176471, 0.172549, 0.176471, 0.184314, \
0.164706, 0.180392, 0.176471, 0.176471, 0.188235, 0.184314, 0.184314, \
0.176471, 0.188235, 0.168627, 0.180392, 0.168627, 0.176471, 0.180392, \
0.188235, 0.180392, 0.176471, 0.180392, 0.184314, 0.168627, 0.184314, \
0.203922, 0.192157, 0.192157, 0.184314, 0.188235, 0.184314, 0.176471, \
0.172549, 0.184314, 0.180392, 0.180392, 0.188235, 0.188235, 0.184314, \
0.196078, 0.188235, 0.184314, 0.188235, 0.184314, 0.188235, 0.192157, \
0.211765, 0.192157, 0.192157, 0.188235, 0.192157, 0.203922, 0.203922, \
0.196078, 0.203922, 0.196078, 0.207843, 0.192157, 0.215686, 0.219608, \
0.207843, 0.211765, 0.211765, 0.203922, 0.215686, 0.223529, 0.215686, \
0.219608, 0.223529, 0.219608, 0.223529, 0.231373, 0.231373, 0.235294, \
0.219608, 0.227451, 0.231373, 0.235294, 0.243137, 0.243137, 0.239216, \
0.247059, 0.270588, 0.25098, 0.25098, 0.270588, 0.262745, 0.266667, \
0.270588, 0.258824, 0.286275, 0.290196, 0.294118, 0.282353, 0.294118, \
0.301961, 0.313725, 0.317647, 0.321569, 0.317647, 0.345098, 0.345098, \
0.360784, 0.345098, 0.364706, 0.368627, 0.364706, 0.372549, 0.392157, \
0.372549, 0.384314, 0.411765, 0.431373, 0.403922, 0.4, 0.419608, \
0.431373, 0.447059, 0.45098, 0.439216, 0.427451, 0.431373, 0.447059, \
0.466667, 0.529412, 0.537255, 0.533333, 0.517647, 0.466667, 0.45098, \
0.407843, 0.411765, 0.423529, 0.415686, 0.45098, 0.466667, 0.470588, \
0.466667, 0.498039, 0.498039, 0.45098, 0.462745, 0.466667, 0.47451, \
0.494118, 0.494118, 0.560784, 0.603922, 0.662745, 0.639216, 0.654902, \
0.627451, 0.615686, 0.619608, 0.611765, 0.6, 0.615686, 0.658824, \
0.670588, 0.643137, 0.65098, 0.619608, 0.682353, 0.678431, 0.639216, \
0.619608, 0.647059, 0.67451, 0.631373, 0.654902, 0.678431, 0.631373, \
0.635294, 0.654902, 0.666667, 0.67451, 0.67451, 0.678431, 0.666667, \
0.666667, 0.690196, 0.67451, 0.686275, 0.67451, 0.662745, 0.686275, \
0.658824, 0.666667, 0.662745, 0.654902, 0.678431, 0.662745, 0.666667, \
0.662745, 0.694118, 0.686275, 0.666667, 0.690196, 0.678431, 0.67451, \
0.686275, 0.647059, 0.65098, 0.627451, 0.654902, 0.631373, 0.611765, \
0.619608, 0.611765, 0.588235, 0.596078, 0.576471, 0.596078, 0.584314, \
0.592157, 0.584314, 0.592157, 0.611765, 0.564706, 0.588235, 0.584314, \
0.560784, 0.564706, 0.576471, 0.54902, 0.564706, 0.556863, 0.556863, \
0.537255, 0.537255, 0.533333, 0.517647, 0.494118, 0.490196, 0.498039, \
0.470588, 0.486275, 0.482353, 0.462745, 0.470588, 0.47451, 0.478431, \
0.482353, 0.466667, 0.470588, 0.47451, 0.443137, 0.427451, 0.411765, \
0.4, 0.415686, 0.407843, 0.403922, 0.392157, 0.407843, 0.396078, \
0.392157, 0.376471, 0.376471, 0.360784, 0.368627, 0.376471, 0.364706, \
0.360784, 0.341176, 0.337255, 0.333333, 0.329412, 0.321569, 0.313725, \
0.309804, 0.309804, 0.313725, 0.286275, 0.290196, 0.27451, 0.286275, \
0.266667, 0.282353, 0.298039, 0.282353, 0.262745, 0.266667, 0.278431, \
0.254902, 0.258824, 0.25098, 0.239216, 0.243137, 0.25098, 0.239216, \
0.243137, 0.258824, 0.239216, 0.223529, 0.239216, 0.243137, 0.235294, \
0.227451, 0.223529, 0.231373, 0.227451, 0.215686, 0.215686, 0.219608, \
0.215686, 0.215686, 0.207843, 0.215686, 0.215686, 0.207843, 0.211765, \
0.203922, 0.2, 0.192157, 0.2, 0.188235, 0.196078, 0.188235, 0.192157, \
0.188235, 0.172549, 0.188235, 0.196078, 0.172549, 0.176471, 0.2, \
0.180392, 0.184314, 0.184314, 0.176471, 0.192157, 0.180392, 0.176471, \
0.192157, 0.176471, 0.176471, 0.180392, 0.176471, 0.188235, 0.156863, \
0.184314, 0.172549, 0.164706, 0.176471, 0.188235, 0.172549, 0.168627, \
0.164706, 0.172549, 0.176471, 0.164706, 0.168627, 0.168627, 0.176471, \
0.192157, 0.180392, 0.168627, 0.160784, 0.164706, 0.168627, 0.168627, \
0.172549, 0.180392, 0.172549, 0.172549, 0.164706, 0.172549, 0.168627, \
0.172549, 0.160784, 0.156863, 0.164706, 0.176471, 0.156863, 0.176471, \
0.172549, 0.164706, 0.180392, 0.172549, 0.160784, 0.172549, 0.164706, \
0.168627, 0.164706, 0.164706, 0.168627, 0.164706, 0.168627, 0.164706};

 Manipulate[
 Show[data, global = {a, b, x0, c}; 
  Plot[a + b*Exp[-((x - x0)^2)/(2 c^2)], {x, 0, 700}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All]], {a, 0.01, 0.9, 0.01}, {b, 
  0.01, 0.9, 0.01}, {x0, 300, 600, 1}, {c, 0.01, 100, 0.1}]
Dynamic@global
```

From here I want to use the values of global in the fit model `g[a_, b_, x0_, c_] := a + b*Exp[-((x - x0)^2)/(2 c^2)]` and use it to extract the FWHM of the profile. But I can't figure out how to assign the list of values from `Dynamic` to the fit model

I would welcome any suggestions to improve the code as well since I don't believe it is a good. I apologize if the list is too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a better approach is to let Mathematica find the best coefficients. Using your data

```
f[x_] := a + b*Exp[-((x - x0)^2)/(2 c^2)];
fit = FindFit[data, f[x], {a, b, c, {x0, 200}}, x]
{a -> 0.169627, b -> 0.503936, c -> 54.9195, x0 -> 194.807}

Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[f[x] /. fit, {x, 0, 400}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the thing is that I have 84 profiles which their FWHM changes by a lot. I tried using this idea but it did not turn out to be very efficient. Do you have any suggestions about the problem that I have with `Dymanic`?

Comment: @saeid Could you potentially `Map` the approach used here onto your 84 profiles, to avoid the dynamic yet not have to do this by hand for each?  That could make a nice table of your FWHM parameters for each case.

Comment: @Ghersic I think I can do that. Thanks for the suggestion. The code that bil has given is very nice and smooth.

Comment: @saeid No problem.  If you're familiar with pure functions, it would likely be `fits = FindFit[#, f[x], {a, b, c, {x0, 200}}, x] & /@ {dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3, ...}` .  That would make a list of all the fits, and then similarly a `Map` (`/@`) pure function using code similar to his `Show[ListPlot ...]` final line to see each with its data.

Comment: @Ghersic This certainly makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to eyeball a fit to the data, particularly for multiple data sets, would be very time consuming and unlikely to give the best fit.

Use [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) with constraints on the parameters and an initial estimate for `x0` taken automatically from the data.

For whatever calculations are to be done on each data set, define a [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) to return the desired information. For example,

```
info[data_List] := Module[
  {nlm, min, max, hmv, hm},
  {model -> (nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data,
        {a + b*Exp[-((x - x0)^2)/(2 c^2)],
         b > 0, c > 0, x0 > 0},
        {a, b, c,
         {x0, Position[data, Max[data]][[1, 1]]}}, x]) // Normal,
   parameters -> nlm["BestFitParameters"],
   minimum -> (min = MinValue[{nlm // Normal, 1 <= x <= Length[data]}, x]),
   maximum -> (max = MaxValue[nlm // Normal, x]),
   halfMax -> (hmv = Mean[{min, max}]),
   halfMaxArg -> (x /. (hm = Solve[{(nlm // Normal) == hmv}, x] // Quiet)),
   fullWidthHalfMax -> Subtract @@ (x /. hm // Reverse)}]
```

For the data set given

```
info1 = info[data]

(* {model -> 0.169627 + 0.503936 E^(-0.000165774 (-194.807 + x)^2), 
 parameters -> {a -> 0.169627, b -> 0.503936, c -> 54.9195, x0 -> 194.807}, 
 minimum -> 0.170096, maximum -> 0.673563, halfMax -> 0.42183, 
 halfMaxArg -> {130.188, 259.426}, fullWidthHalfMax -> 129.239} *)

Plot[Tooltip[model /. info1],
 {x, 1, Length@data},
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 Prolog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[3],
   Point[Transpose@{Range@Length@data, data}],
   Green, Tooltip[Line[{#, halfMax /. info1} & /@ (halfMaxArg /. info1)],
    Row[{"FWHM = ", fullWidthHalfMax /. info1}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bob for the code. I learned a lot from this. I will have to spend some time on figuring out on what you have written here.